# How and when to use groups?

Tags: permissions

I have only one user on my computer, and I never set any group permissions. When are they useful? Can you give me a few examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example is that, by default the Apache web server runs as user and group `www-data`.

Your user ID is not `www-data`, nor is your default group ID.  You can't arbitrarily change your user ID and retain the integrity of your access, but you can add your username to a group and have access to files that are not normally available to a normal user.

You could add your user id to the `www-data` group with the command:

```
$ sudo adduser [username] [groupname]
```

After that command the user with the username will have access to files with the groupname.  By the way, you won't use the brackets.  The brackets in the example is to show you a variable that can be replaced.

Now you could create files on your web server that you could edit.  The server itself would be able to make updates to the files also

By the way you can remove a user from a group with:

```
$ sudo deluser [username] [groupname]
```

There are many other group access examples that you could find just by looking at the various groups that are available by default.  You can check the group list with:

```
$ less /etc/group
```

You'll probably notice that your username has access to a number of system features such as `plugdev` (the feature that give access to usb devices that you might attach to your computer).  You'll may also notice that you have access to the cdrom device (the `cdrom` group).

An important one is the `sudo` group, which allows you to use the elevated/super user commands.

**An for using the `www-data` group access**

I used www-data as an example.  By default the web files are owned by root.  They are not available to be edited by other users.  You can specify the files to a different group according to who you want to have access to be able to edit the files.  Then you can give access to those people (including the web server) access.

Since the web server  is running under the user and group ID, www-data, you could give the web server access to making changes to files by changing them to that user or group.  By default your web server can't make changes to any of the web files.

If you had a reason for your server to make changes to certain web files (or folders) that would be an occasion to change the files (or folders) to that specific user or group.

**Creating a group**

Thank in consideration that you might also have an occasion where you want to give specific access to particular files or folders to yourself and to other userID's.  You can create a group specific for that and add access to that group with the commands above.

A commandline for creating a group is:

```
$ sudo addgroup <groupname>
```

There might be an occasion where you might write a program to perform specific task.  You could create a user and group ID for that program.  Place the files and folders that the program will be accessing (reading and writing to) in that group with the command above.

The FTP daemon and protocol is an example.  If you wanted to allow people to upload files to your computer, you would create a specific directory and give write access via user or group to that directory so that the FTP daemon can write to it.

You wouldn't want the FTP daemon to be able to write anywhere on your system.  So you would specify by user or group access where the FTP daemon can read or write.

**Note**

*Notice the `$` in front of the terminal commands.  This is an indicator of the command prompt from a normal user's login session.  If the command was coming from the root login the default prompt is the `#` symbol.
When logged in as a normal user, yuo have to prefix your command with the `sudo` command to elevate the access to the super doer.  This isn't necessary it you're logged in as root.  Also it's easy to look at the text and see with commands needs to be elevated, such as `adduser`.  Notice teh `/etc/group` is (by default) world readable, so you don't need the elevated command (root access) to read the content.  You would need it to write to it.*

Comment: Um, which files are available for  www-data only? Groups have any other power except file access permissions?

Comment: I'll update my answer with a formatted response to your comment within the hour.